# Pandas 'Weeknum' to 'Week of'

Tags: python, pandas

I need to retrieve the 'Week of' from a date series in pandas, with the week starting on Sunday.
Example Data:

```
Dates
10/3/2016
10/9/2016
10/10/2016
10/10/2016
```

In the above data, 10/3/2016 would fall in the 'Week of' 10/2/16 and the rest of the data would fall in the 'Week of' 10/9/16, as those would be the first sundays on those weeks.

I know how to obtain a weeknumber from a date in pandas, but how could I convert that weeknumber to a 'Week of'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# only if 'date' column is not datetime format:    
date_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_df['date'])

df['week_start'] = \
    df['date'] - ((date_df['date'].dt.weekday + 1) % 7).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: This accomplished it perfectly! Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# make a datetime object for your date ('10/3/2016')
date = datetime.strptime('10/31/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')

# weekday() returns 0 for monday so add 1 
day_delta = date.weekday() + 1

# get week start date as string
start_date = date - timedelta(days=day_delta)
start_str = start_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

The pandas part:

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming that you have a DataFrame with the dates as strings
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['week_start'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: (x - timedelta(x.weekday + 1)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have mentioned you know how to get weeknumber from date in pandas , create a column which has week number. Create a dict to have a week number to date mapping, example -

```
{'52':'2016/12/20',....}
```

Now,create a function to reference to read from the dict for every row in the pandas dataframe and assign a value to another column that states 
'Week of value_from_dictionary'

All you need to do the above things are 
apply function (for pandas)
datetime (python)

Comment: How would I generate a date from the weeknumber? For example:
`pd.date_range(start="1/1/16", periods=52, freq='W')`
This creates a list where the 52nd week is '2016-12-25'.

How would I make a date of '2016-12-26' fall into the week of '2016-12-25'?

Comment: I think this is a pretty terrible way to go about it since you'd have to define a new dictionary for every year by hand. The other answer, while less descriptive, is actually better.